# Fabric won't leave play framework 1.2 running

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, fabric, playframework-1.x

I have an automated job that starts a remote play framework 1.2 application.

ssh @ "play start --%prod"

This successfully starts the play application and leaves it running (the play start command spawns a child process).

If I try and use fabric to run the same command, it will start the application and then kill it when the connect is closed.

run('play start --%prod && sleep 5')

Play framework will spawn the child java process and it will run for the 5 seconds of sleep, and then be killed (the sleep is purely for debug purposes).

I have tried with an without -l in the env.shell variable but has the same result.

env.shell = '/bin/bash -l -c' and env.shell = '/bin/bash -c'

I am currently sshing as the same user that owns the process. Ideally I would want to use the "sudo('play start xxxxx', user=)" method of fabric in order to remove requirement connecting directly as the applications user. But am unable to get this to work either.

"nohup" DOES work, but it would be preferable to see the output of play and handle errors if it fails to start. "play stop" and "play status" work fine.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Im curious.

Comment: unfortunately not yet